# Why System64 and mono and system in My Notebook D Drive?

Tags: mono, system

12/27 i use stream install SCP:secret laboratory but 12/29 i turn on my notebook i find System64 and System and mono folder in my Notebook D Drive , I have uninstalled SCP:secret laboratory  ,should i delete this three folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be safe to delete those folders. They are a requirement for SCP:SL.

If you're worried about breaking something, I would recommend moving the folders to see if something breaks (unlikely), and once you're sure everything is still OK, you can safely delete them.